# Best way to access AWS RDS from AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I have Java based containers running AWS ECS Fargate. Now we are accessing AWS RDS Postgres database via username-password combo, but I wonder how to make this process more secure.

But I have a concern: **How to avoid storing user passwords in .psql scripts** (`CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'xxx'`)? I think better option will be to avoid using passwords completely, but I am not sure how to do it...

Loading passwords to Fargate containers is from AWS Secrets Manager - this is OK.

Do you have any advice, please?

---

**EDIT: I will share my progress here so anyone can reproduce** 
Docs: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/.../.../.../UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html)

**- PHASE ONE -** 
**Goal**: PoC of IAM Auth (using IAM User)

1. [I have prepared my RDS instance to allow IAM Auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Enabling.html)
2. I have created IAM user, [attached new IAM Policy to it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html) and create an access key.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds-db:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds-db:eu-central-1:666:dbuser:db-YFVS/iam_user"
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE**: In the resource is used resourceId, not arn! (this can be found in the Configuration tab of the rds instance)

3. [I have created user in my database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.DBAccounts.html)

```
CREATE USER iam_user; 
GRANT rds_iam TO iam_user;
```

4. [I tested the connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.PostgreSQL.html) (after exporting access key)

```
# Generate token
export RDSHOST="dev.aaaaa.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
export PGPASSWORD="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 5432 --region eu-central-1 --username iam_user )"

#Connect
psql "host=$RDSHOST port=5432 dbname=mydb user=iam_user password=$PGPASSWORD"

mydb->
```

Now I would like to proceed with Java implementation and furthermore move to Fargate

**- PHASE TWO -** 
**Goal**: Implement IAM Auth into Python app
I have followed the tutorial here and it worked fine. I have used IAM credentials (key, secret) of the IAM user I created in the previous step. Also, I have loaded creds from ENVs instead of profile file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import boto3

ENDPOINT="postgresmydb.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
PORT="5432"
USR="jane_doe"
REGION="us-east-1"
DBNAME="mydb"

session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1',
                        aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USR, Region=REGION)

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=ENDPOINT, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, user=USR, password=token)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
    query_results = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_results)
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
```

Comment: If using `AWS Secrets Manager` is OK, they why not do this?

Comment: @Marcin because we have passwords stored in plaintext in .psql scripts (where user is created), I would like to avoid storing passwords there or avoid using passwords completely (if possible)

Comment: I see, RDS PostgreSQL supports [IAM Database Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html). With this you  "you don't need to use a password". Have you considered that?

Comment: @Marcin I think this might be the key. I was asking because I was not sure whether this is the best option - we will try to implement this and in case of success, I will share the result. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I will make an answer with the suggestion. Later you can let me know how did it go, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Marcin sure, okay!

Comment: add db creds to secrets manager encrypted with KMS and use them as environment variables in your ECS Cluster.
Read environment variable at application startup extract credentials and use them , no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

A way to not used password for accessing RDS PostgreSQL is to use [IAM Database Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html):

> With this authentication method, you **don't need to use a password** when you connect to a DB instance. Instead, you use an authentication token.

There are some [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Limitations) to consider, one of which is:

> The maximum number of connections per second for your DB instance might be limited depending on its DB instance class and your workload.

Comment: btw do I understand correctly that I have to create the **policy** to determine which db users are allowed to auth and then attach this policy to the **taskRole**?
*There is no way how to create a separate role and attach it to the ecs task?*

Comment: @FilipNiko I think it should be taskExecution role. But I would suggest first to set it up for test in most simple scenario, e.g. test IAM user, if the procedure is new. For IAM role maybe easy it would be to test using EC2 with instance role.  Then once you are comfortable with setting this up, you can move onto Fargate.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to do it using IAM User first. Thx

Comment: @FilipNiko No problem. Please let me know how it will go.

Comment: I just proved RDS IAM Auth works for IAM User. But how to take step further and remove IAM User and use the role only? Since we are using Java, we should call RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator, but in the example, they are adding credentials. I though this will be avoided using **taskRole**/**taskExecution** so the ECS will be privileged to call auth directly, am I right?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.AuthToken

Comment: according to **Attaching an IAM Policy to an IAM User or Role** in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html, what I would like to achieve should be possible

Comment: @FilipNiko Yes. I think that the required policy should be added to [task execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html). Java AWS SDK should be able to get the credentials from the role without you needing to do anything. `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` [can use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default) the role by itself.